# Windows 7 upgrade path

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

A while ago I was given a German Windows Vista Ultimate (both 64bit and 32bit on separate disks) during a Micosoft promotion event. Now I am not sure what kind of version I got here (maybe you can help me out). On the disks is written that it includes Windows Anytime Upgrade and that I is not allowed to resell it. There is also an item number on the disk: X12-73442-01 (64bit) and X12-73358 (32bit).

Would I be able to upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate with this? If so how much would it most likely cost me?

Comment: Sounds like a collector's item.  I'd stick it on eBay and see what it'd go for!  (You can ignore the "not allowed to resell" bit, that's not enforcable -- a gift-giver can't restrict what the gift-recipient does with the gift once it's given!)

Comment: Quack, You shouldn't really be making claims like that. The licence is  non-transferable. Reselling it would break the EULA (because he actually does not have the right to sell/profit from something that isn't his) which could, depending on your country, be illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Run (Start > run), run `winver`. It should tell you what version of Windows you are running. Using that information and the [chart below](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=1246), you should be able to determine your releveant upgrade path

[image]

Comment: Also see this link: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/get/anytime-upgrade-overview.aspx

Comment: I says I have Windows Vista Ultimate. I knew that already. But how do I known what Uiltimate I have (OEM, System builder or whatever is out there) and if I am allowed to upgrade with this version?

Comment: Windows Vista Ultimate is Windows Vista Ultimate, regardless of the purchasing licence. It does not matter if it is OEM, retail or otherwise. You can still upgrade it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you will be able to use your previous version of Windows Vista to perform an upgrade install of Windows 7. For more assistance with this process Microsoft does have an official Windows 7 RC Support Forum located here http://tinyurl.com/9fhdl5 . It is supported by product specialists as well as engineers and support teams.

Also, you can pre-order your copy of Windows 7 Home Premium or Windows 7 Professional today. For more information, see the Windows 7 Pre-Order offer page here: [Windows 7 Pre-Order](http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/buy/offers/pre-order-ended.aspx)
Also, if you are currently a student you may qualify for the $30 upgrade to Windows 7. For more information, please go here: [Windows 7 Upgrade](http://windows7.digitalriver.com/store/mswpus/en_US/DisplayHomePage?resid=IIqm7AoBAiMAAGKgLTYAAABE&rests=1254763657481)