# IDE controller compatibility problem during Windows 7 x64 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, compatibility, ide-controller

I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium x64 and upgrading to Windows 7 Home Premium x64. While Windows 7 Upgrade was collecting information just before loading the new system, it says:

> These devices might not work properly
>   after the upgrade. Before upgrading,
>   we recommend updating the drivers for
>   these devices. Cancel the upgrade,
>   open Control Panel and search for
>   "update device drivers", or go to the
>   device manufacturer's website to
>   search for updated drivers.
>
> Storage controllers: AMO1YI57 IDE
>   Controller

It recommends me to update its driver before installation, but the driver is already up-to-date.

What should I do?

**Note:** Motherboard is GBaByte P43-ES3G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will bet an honest Abe that it found a driver in your Vista 64 bit that isn't signed by "Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher", and the Windows 7 installer is complaining about it.
And in order to make sure everything works after the upgrade, it will warn you.

Wither or not it would be safe to continue, I don't know the exact answer. If you have data you want saved then I would make an image with it with some program like DriveXML or http://selfimage.excelcia.org/ ...otherwise if you can stand to lose whatever data you had on it, then try it anyways.
I am not saying blindly leap forth, but if you can't find a newer driver, then backup and try continuing anyways.

Comment: OK, I see... I've already backed up the data, but the problem is: If I continue, it will take approximately 14-15 hours to upgrade (see http://superuser.com/questions/52740/upgrade-from-windows-vista-x64-to-windows-7-x64) and if it fails, I will be regretful to lose a lot of time. But I think it's worth to take a shot anyway. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing on google matches your controller and you don't say what motherboard you have, so this is tough to help you with.

Check with your motherboard vendor to see if there is an updated driver for the IDE controller.  You may need to use the F6 option during install when asked for additional drivers (or use the advanced option in the GUI), and then provide it with media containing updated drivers from the motherboard vendor.

Alternately, phone Microsoft.  You get 90 days of support if you've just bought it.

Comment: Added motherboard info. I checked vendor site but my drivers are up-to-date. However, I've found something very similar to my problem on the net: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090727030937AAmy6sz
He claims that the best option is to make a clean install, which I don't want to have to...

Comment: Are you saying the Vista drivers are up to date?  If so, this does not matter.  The installer boots from the DVD, and it is the drivers on DVD, loaded by the installer which matter during the install phase.  The installer will not use your drivers on hard disk to enable the IDE device (at least not until the first phase of the installer is complete).  If those drivers from Microsoft are not up to date on Microsoft's DVD, then you need to specify the drivers during the installation.