# Storage driver difficulties stop me installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, storage

I'm having a driver problem. When I try to install Windows 7 over Vista it says my storage driver isn't compatible and I should get a better driver before upgrading. The storage driver is called "AIW32FM3 IDE Controller" and I can't find its name anywhere on Google. The automatic driver searching things don't work and I have no idea how to get a newer one.

I've got two internal hard drives, one from Seagate and one from Western Digital, but I can't find newer drivers on their website and have no idea what model/serial number or anything like that they are.

Can someone please help me upgrade my storage driver so I can install Windows 7, or tell me if I can install Windows 7 anyway and still be fine?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience while upgrading from Vista to 7, and I chose to continue after the warning message. If I were in your shoes, I would back up my system and execute the upgrade. You may want to take a look at what I've done through the process:

- [IDE controller compatibility problem during Win7 x64 upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/63962/ide-controller-compatibility-problem-during-win7-x64-upgrade)
- [Windows 7 does not recognize Media Card Reader after upgrade from Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/64417/windows-7-does-not-recognize-media-card-reader-after-upgrade-from-vista)

Comment: Argh, one of the reasons I need to upgrade to 7 is I don't have a decent backup solution and was hoping to use 7's full-disc imaging.

Answer (score 0):

IDE controller is a motherboard device, Mehper has your answer for that.

Here is another program you can run in Vista before upgrading, it will check all your peripheral devices also.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx

> Before scanning your PC with the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor, be sure to plug in and power on any USB devices or other devices, such as printers, external hard disks, and scanners, that you regularly use with the PC you're checking.