# Can I upgrade from Vista Home Premium x64 to 7 x64 without losing any of my files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-7-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade from Windows Vista (x64) to Windows 7 (x64)](https://superuser.com/questions/52740/upgrade-from-windows-vista-x64-to-windows-7-x64)

I have been using Vista HP x64 for around two years now, and recently 7 caught me and I decided to upgrade. The bad part of this is that I don't have an external hard drive to back up my files.

Does an upgrade give the option to keep every file from the previous installation?
I can re-install my software without any hassle but the file do matter a lot.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/52740/upgrade-from-windows-vista-x64-to-windows-7-x64

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/50295/windows-7-upgrade-path

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever need to reformat.  When you choose a Custom install instead of an in-place upgrade, formatting your harddrive is optional.

It's been like that since the days of Win 2000.  What Setup will do is move all your old files into a folder called `Windows.old`.  Then when Setup is done, you can just drag and drop you files out of the folder to where ever you want.